# Function that can apply list changes to other lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, list, data-analysis

I am searching for a function that can apply position changes in a list to other lists.
For example:

```
liste1 = [3, 4, 1] 
liste2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
liste1.sort()   #so liste1 = [1,3,4]
if liste1 = [1,3,4] :
   liste2 = ['c', 'a', 'b']
```

I can change positions of `liste2` myself, but I have 270,000 values, which is why I am searching for a function that can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could zip the lists together, sort them then unzip them.

```py
liste1 = [3, 4, 1] 
liste2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
merged_lists = sorted(zip(liste1, liste2))
liste1, liste2 = zip(*merged_lists)
print(liste1, liste2, sep="\n")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
(1, 3, 4)
('c', 'a', 'b')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that exactly what I wanted